# How to take action for users using android accessibility service?

Tags: android, accessibility

We have started to look into the Building Accessibility Service for Android at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html. Based on this documentation, we can perform custom gestures on behalf of user as mentioned under section "Taking actions for users" at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#act-for-users.
We have following questions based on this documentation.

1) As we understand, there are gestures that user would perform and our code would listen to. Let's call these Listening Gestures. Then there are gestures that could be performed by our code for user. Let's call these Performing Gestures. Question is where do Performing Gestures impact - over touch-and-explore layer or underneath the touch-and-explore layer? For additional information, touch-and-explore is feature of Android Operating System that can be requested by Accessibility Services.

2) Does the Performing Gesture trigger any AccessibilityEvent which is notified to Accessibility Service? If yes, there's possible recursion if both Listening Gesture and Performing Gesture happen to be same. That is Listening Gesture could be swipe right which triggers some event. Performing Gesture is also let's say a swipe right. Now, this will also in turn trigger same event handler.

3) How do we determine that Performing Gesture executed successfully? The whole thing holds significance if Performing Gesture happens underneath the touch-and-explore layer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, performing gestures on behalf of users utilizing Accessibility service capabilities DOES NOT end up being caught as a "listening" gesture. The AccessibilityService actually sends the gesture through to the API that calculates screen touches in the exact same way that the screen does, circumventing the screen completely. So, these events are invisible to the assisstive technology. Though, if you hang on to a reference, you could of course call the callbacks from AccessibilityService for these gestures yourself. So, any gesture you perform will not trigger a touch to explore gesture. In fact, you could trigger performing a gesture as a result of a touch to explore gesture.

2) This, to me is actually the same question as question 1. No, it does not, because of all of the same reasons in question 1.

3) There are two answers to this. The first is 'dispatchGesture' returns a boolean. This boolean is true when the operating system runs into no technical issues dispatching your gesture. Potential issues for example would be: Your attempting to interact off screen. This would be stupid of you! LOL. If a "true" is returned from this method, your gesture was generally accpetable and was performed. At this point, we can be as sure that a gesture was performed as a user actually performing the gesture themselves. It's the exact same logic in the Operating System... check out the AOSP for yourself if you don't believe me :)

3B) The only way to be sure things are working is to watch your gesture take actions on the screen.